# nginx remove query string from specific URL

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301

So Google have indexed ~60k URL's with query parameters on sub pages of a WordPress install.

For example: `http://domain.com/browse/page/35/?resource=pdf`

What I need to do is issue a 301 redirect to the same URL but without `?resource=pdf` (some URL's have multiple queries).

I've tried a couple of code snippets from SO, but nothing that works.

Any ideas?

Edit:

This is what I'm currently trying, but results in a redirect loop:

```
location ^~ /browse/ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Simple `return 301 $uri;` should do

Comment: I get a `Restarting nginx: Terminated` when I try that.

Comment: Then you should first check config and fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $arg_resource ) {
    return http://domain.com$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

You can also do it with `return 301...` in my example

Comment: I would suggest that `$uri` from the core module is more appropriate than `$fastcgi_script_name` from the FastCGI module.